# How to style dynamically based on current bootstrap column widths

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4+.  Looking for best practices for how to style bootstrap columns based on the current width.  Consider this simple code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="margin: 10px;" id="part1"></div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-6" style="margin: 10px;" id="part2"></div>
```

When the viewport is xs and each part is showing full width, I want zero margins.  When looking at it on a medium and larger monitor I want margins to be 10px.  What is best practice to get this done?

Should I use ngClass to call a class (.my-margin) based on another class (col-md-6) because I can't seem to get that working right.  What is best practice that you all find helpful?

TIA and happy hump day.

Comment: you can use media query to only set margin: 10px if viewport is larger than a certain size

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I know about this method but am looking for more of a general best practice for dealing with the different col breakpoints for styling.  I just found the spacing guide https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/ which would allow me to add a class like "ml-md-2" to get me what I want as well.  In my haste to write the example I sloppily wrote margins instead of padding for this situation - margins would force another col break with how I wrote the example - sorry for the confusion.